# Unity2D Touch event on just 1 object instead of all

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

So i have a script that detects TAP and does something when i tap on an 2D object with a collider atached to it.My problem is that i have this on 3 separate objects and if i click any of them they all move(all have the same script and i cant put diferent scripts because i have 11 objects and i might have 2 of the same objects in the same scene on one of those 3). Please help.Here is my code:

```
void Update()
{
     if(platform == RuntimePlatform.Android || platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
{
 if(Input.touchCount > 0)
   {
    if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
       {
         checkTouch(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
       }
    }
  }
}

void checkTouch(Vector3 pos)
{
  Vector3 wp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
  Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(wp.x, wp.y);
  var hit = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos);

  if(hit.collider2D)
   {
     Move();
   }
}
```

Comment: `Input.GetTouch(0)` just returns the first touch. Loop over all the touches with `for(int i=0; i<Input.touchCount; i++)`

Comment: post the `Move()` function please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you should do is to send the information of the object you hit to
your `Move()` method so the method knows what to move you can send it like this
`if(hit.collider2D)
      {
       Move(hit.collider2D.gameObject);
       }`

and `hit` is  a `collider2D` so you can do it like this
`if(hit)
     {
      Move(hit.gameObject);
     }`